# grails write file in memory only writes one line

Tags: grails, download

trying to write a multiline file and then have it download:

```
def download() {
    file.write("line1\n")
    file.write("line2\n")
    response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=testalex.txt"
    response.contentType = 'text-plain'
    response.outputStream << file.text
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

However the file only displays line2.  What is the reason for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sergio's approach Or use `append` for "line2" :)

```
......
file.write("line1\n")
file.append("line2\n")
......
```

[append](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#append%28java.lang.Object%29) appends text to the end of the file. I like withWriter (@Sergio's approach) though.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#write%28java.lang.String%29):

> write(String text)
>   Write the text to the File.

So you're replacing your content in the file each time you use `write()`. You can look in the Groovy docs about [Input and Output](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Input+Output). Example:

```
file.withWriter { out ->
  out.writeLine("line1") //no need to add the \n, the out will handle.
  out.writeLine("line2")
}
```